# Ramp down users in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

```
val scn = scenario("CoreScenarios")
    .during(2 minutes){
       exec(Login.login, Flow.flow, ChangeAddress.changeaddress, Wrapup.wrapup, Flow2.flow2)
}

val scn1 = scenario("Logout").exec(Logout.logout)

  setUp(
  scn.inject(rampUsers(20) during (1 minutes)).protocols(httpProtocol)
    .andThen(
       **scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1))**.protocols(httpProtocol))
      )
```

scn will loop login, flow, change address and flow2 for 2 minutes with 20 users.
scn1 is the logout scenario and I want the same(active) 20 users to logout. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Gatling works. A scenario is a complete journey.
What you want is a single scenario where your virtual users first log in, then loop on some actions, then log out.

I recommend you have a look at the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/) and or [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stephane, the requirement that I have is I have 20 uses who needs to login into the system in 1 minute and all the 20 users available in the system executing flow, changeaddress, wrapup and flow2 scenarios for  1 more minute(that is the reason I used during in 'core scenario') and execute the logout scenario because in our application, if we logout, the no of users will go down. Any thoughts?

Comment: As I said, use a loop, typically during. Please have a look at the documentation and take the free online courses. Really.

Comment: Thank you Stephane!, but the only problem that I have is between login and logout I have multiple scenarios.. if I use during in a scenario, that scenario will loop for that duration, how do I loop multiple scenarios using single 'during'? as I said I need flow, change address, wrapup and flow2 (sequential flows) to loop through for a time interval.

Comment: Stephane, if I understood you correctly, you want me to add the 'During' loop in the actual scenario right? I did that to the 'flow' scenario, but it is only the flow scenario that loops for the time interval, but in this scenario I need flow, changeaddress,wrapup and flow2 scenarios(sequentially) in one single loop. I wasn't sure on how to combine multiple scenarios, that is the reason, I added the 'during' while defining the scenario as shown above. Hope I am not confusing you. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to run a simulation like this:

```
val loginScn = scenario("Login").exec(Login.login)
val coreScn = scenario("Core")
    .exec(Flow.flow)
    .exec(ChangeAddress.changeaddress)
    .exec(Wrapup.wrapup)
    .exec(Flow2.flow2)
val logoutScn = scenario("Logout").exec(Logout.logout)

setUp(loginScn.inject(rampUsers(20) during (1.minutes))
    .andThen(coreScn.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(20).during(1.minutes)))
    .andThen(logoutScn.inject(atOnceUsers(20)))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

In any case, consider a revision of the requirement, since performance tests are not generally performed in this way.